# hybrid application development

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I Have an Application which works on all the platforms like ios,andriod and web. What I need to know is, is there any way to delete all the js files and all the data from the device on getting a delete trigger(it could be a notification or 3 password invalid case). Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: You can't delete the js files, but if your data is stored in localStorage or the likes, I'm pretty sure you can delete the data.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no. An app can't delete itself, since it would need elevated privileges (root) to modify the system, even when it only wants to remove itself.

Comment: But is there any way to delete the folder containing the js files?

Comment: or any other ways to invalidate my .apk or .ipa

Comment: No, same reason as I stated before. These files are protected by the system and can only be removed through the settings of the phone. What you could do, is remove the user settings, since those are handled by the app itself. That way at least the user's data will be gone.